# Print line matching the expression and 5th line after the matching expression line

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

i have a file like this

```
pin
port
coord
some info
some more info

pin
port
coord
some info
some more info
```

I wanted to grep "`pin`" and "`some info`" into a file

i tried `grep -A 3 pin input.txt | sed -n '4~5p'`

this only gives me "`someinfo`" line.

i want my output as

```
pin
some info

pin
some info
```

any suggestion in awk, sed etc..!!!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: output should be pin \n someinfo \n .. and so on

Comment: You say you want the 5th line after pin but then your expected output is the 3rd line after it. You show you want a blank line between records in your output but then state that answers without that are correct. You say you want the line containing pin plus the Nth line after it, but then state that answers that instead just grep for `pin|some info` are correct. Please clarify your question as it's now VERY unclear what you actually are trying to do.

Comment: @user3044691 it is still unclear what you wanted on this question, you could clarify or accept the one that made the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/pin/{print; n=0} ++n==4{print $0 ORS}' file
pin
some info

pin
some info
```

or if you don't need the blank line between output records:

```
$ awk '/pin/{print;n=0} ++n==4' file
pin
some info
pin
some info

$ awk '/pin/{n=0} ++n~/^[14]$/' file
pin
some info
pin
some info
```

Comment: Very nice. I knew there was a better solution than mine in there somewhere but clearly didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example select every line `4k` and `4k+1`:

```
$ grep -A 3 --no-group-separator "pin" file | awk 'NR%4<=1'
pin
some info
pin
some info
```

Note the importance of `--no-group-separator`:

```
$ grep -A 3 --no-group-separator "pin" file
pin
port
coord
some info
pin                   # no "--" between matches
port
coord
some info
```

But:

```
$ grep -A 3 "pin" file
pin
port
coord
some info
--
pin
port
coord
some info
```

Comment: Note that this checks "pin" together with the line exactly 3 lines after. If you know you want "some info" and "pin", you can do  directly do `egrep "pin|some info" file`.

Comment: @user3044691 your expected output shows a blank line after `some info`, this answer doesn't provide that but you say it works. Do you want that blank line between output records or not? It changes the solutions we are providing

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print if /pin|some info/;' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: @user3044691 In your question you say you want the line containing `pin` plus the Nth line after it. This solution doesn't provide that, it just greps for `pin|some info` but you say it works. Do you want to find the Nth line after pin or do you just want the lines containing `pin` and `some info`?  It changes the solutions we are providing

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'n==5 {print; n=0} /pin/ {print; n=1} n{n++}' pin.in
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these should work provided that you're actually looking for a line called "some info"

1)`sed -n -e 's/pin/&/p' -e 's/some info/&/p' input.txt`
The `-n` mean by default do not print the line.
The `-e` allows for multiple searches.
The `&` is a reference to the match between the first two `/`.
The `p` means prints what's between the last two `/`.
So all together it searches `input.txt` for `pin` and `some info` and will only print the lines containing them

2)`awk '/pin/ {print} /some info/ {print}'`
This does the same; it searches for `pin` and `some info` and prints only those lines.
The output for both commands is: 

`pin
some info
pin
some info`
If the empty line between the first `some info` and the second `pin` is absolutely necessary, I can try to figure out a way to insert it (probably using `sed`)

EDIT:
I realized that you can actually use `sed -n -e '/pin/p' -e '/some info/p' input.txt` instead of the above `sed` command (no `s` flag and no `&`). It's shorter and more readable this way.

Comment: Then you might as well `grep 'pin\|some info' file` instead.

Comment: True, I was trying to stick with `awk` and `sed` as the question stated, but `grep` would work perfectly (probably even better)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perl -00 -nlE 'say map {"$_\n"} (split /\n/, $_)[0,3]' < filename
```

for the next input:

```
pin
port
coord
some info
some more info

bla
port2
coord2
bla some info2
some more info2
```

prints

```
pin
some info

bla
bla some info2
```